# Logstash wrap json object

Tags: json, logstash, dplyr

I would like to wrap a json object sent to Logstash via the http listener plugin so I can send it off to Splunk. I get an object that looks like:

```
{ 
   "foo" : "text", 
   "bar" : "text" 
}
```

and I need it to look like:

```
{ "event" : 
  { 
     "foo" : "text", 
     "bar" : "text"
  } 
}
```

I just can not find how to access that top level object.

config:

```
input {
  http {
    port => 8080
    codec => "json"
  }
}

filter {
  mutate {
    rename => { "WHAT GOES HERE???" => "event" }
  }
}

output {
  stdout { codec => json }
}
```

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `rename` or `add_field`.

With `rename`

```
mutate {
    rename => { "foo" => "[event][foo]" }
    rename => { "bar" => "[event][bar]" }
}
```

With `add_field`

```
mutate {
    add_field => { "[event][foo]" => "%{[foo]}" }
    add_field => { "[event][bar]" => "%{[bar]}" }
}
```

If you use `add_field`, the fields `foo` and `bar` are kept in the message, you can remove them using `remove_field`

```
mutate {
    remove_field => [ "foo", "bar" ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, that will work, but do you happen to know if I can grab something like "*" or all fields somehow, my object has quite a few more keys then just `foo` and `bar` and I was hoping to avoid putting all in this config.

Comment: Can you share a sample of your object? If it is a json object maybe you can use the json filter to parse it and store the result in a [target field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-json.html#plugins-filters-json-target).

Answer (score 0):

Another elegant way is to use json target within a filter:

```
filter {
   json {
      source => "message"
      target => "event"
   }
}
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-json.html#plugins-filters-json-target